# Rails 4 Error: NoMethodError / undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, undefined

Hey there,
I am fairly new to Rails and I've managed to create a Favorite controller for my Items(Tools) and Users, which works totally fine.
Now I am trying to do the same just in that user module. So users are able to favorite other users.
 I played around, and came up with this:

**I am getting this error in the browser when accessing /users/index view:**

```
NoMethodError in Users#index
undefined method `favorite_user_path' for #<#<Class:0x8ca77b8>:0x8ca50b8>
```

**Here is my code:**

*app/models/favorite_user.rb*

```
class FavoriteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :c_user_id
    belongs_to :user_id
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_many :tools

  # Favorite tools of user
  has_many :favorite_tools # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_tools, source: :tool # the actual tools the user favorites

  # Favorite users of user
  has_many :favorite_users # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_users, source: :user # the actual users the user favorites
  has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favourite_users, source: :user # the actual users favoriting a user



  mount_uploader :avatar_filename, AvatarUploader

end
```

*app/controllers/users_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_user, only: [:show, :favorite]

    # Add and remove favorite recipes
    # for current_user
    def userfavorite
      type = params[:type]
      if type == "favorite"
        current_user.userfavorites << @user

      elsif type == "unfavorite"
        current_user.userfavorites.delete(@user)

      else
        # Type missing, nothing happens
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
      end
    end

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @tools = Tool.where(user_id: @user).order("created_at DESC")
        @tool = Tool.find(1)
    end

    private

    def find_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

*app/views/users/index.html.haml*

```
- @users.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to user.username, user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", favorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", favorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
```

*app/config/routes.rb*

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :userfavorite] do 
    get :userfavorite, on: :member
end
```

I hope the provided data is enough, if not please tell me. I'm grateful for all Your replies.

Comment: Your route is `userfavorite`. So that'd be `userfavorite_user_path`.

Comment: @Ven That works, don't know how I missed that - never copy code from what you've done already and then change something I guess! A question though on the user model: Is it generally possible what I am doing there? Just because I am linking to a model which does not exist, but instead I would like to link to the exact same model I am linking from. Can I just delete this piece of code: 'source: :user'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared any such path in the routes file. As per your routes file you can use named path like

```
userfavorite_user_path(user_id)
```

Comment: That works, don't know how I missed that - never copy code from what you've done already and then change something I guess! A question though on the user model: Is it generally possible what I am doing there?

Comment: Just because I am linking to a model which does not exist, but instead I would like to link to the exact same model I am linking from. Can I just delete this piece of code: 'source: :user'?

Comment: There's a close reason on SO that's "simple typographical error". Answering such questions to get some rep is... well.